# getting json data as undefined in Ajax call

Tags: jquery, json, ajax

Here is my json response

```
"aaData": [
    {
      "name": "XXX",
      "address": "XXX"

    },
]
```

response also coming in the "data" but when i am trying to get the particular property from the json response like below i am getting undefined.

```
 $.each($.parseJSON(data), function(index,value){
    alert(value.name);
});
```

Note: 
in the value variable i am getting list object.
but in the case of value.name getting as undefined

could you please help me out on this.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

1) Add curly braces aroung json object

2) You do not need parseJSON(), you can directly acess using $.each()

```
var jsonP = { "aaData" : [{ "name": "XXX","address": "XXX" }] };

$.each(jsonP.aaData, function(index,value){
    alert(value.name);
});
```

Comment: Tried but not working ,Thanks for the quick response,is there any alternative

Answer (score 0):

maybe the json data should be:

```
{"aaData": [
    {
      "name": "XXX",
      "address": "XXX"

    },
]}
```

Comment: getting same response only.but when i iterating ,getting undefined

Comment: ok...  1. There is extra `，` in the response, do you find it? 2. change  `$.parseJSON(data) ` to `$.parseJSON(data). aaData `

Answer (score 0):

it is an array use array value as zero

```
$.each($.parseJSON(data), function(index,value){
alert(value[0].name);
```

});

Answer (score -1):

$(value).each(function(){alert(this.text);});